# Calculating all values in column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table order_product

[image]

i want to calculate all the values from cost column and quantity column WHERE `order_orderNumber = 1100`

how do i do it.?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'calculate'. Calculate the sum of products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant sum, you can do:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS totalQuantity, SUM(cost) AS totalCost
FROM order_product WHERE order_orderNumber = 1100
GROUP BY product_id
```